# How to trigger a barbarian horde in Europa Universalis: Rome (Vae Victis)

Tags: europa-universalis-rome

I play Macedonia and I've conquered all of Greece and nearly all of the Balkans. I've anexed Daci but one province is left uncolonised (it borders 5 of my provinces and 1 barbarian province) because it has 5 barbarian power.

Unfortunately the chance for a horde is 0% (too much civilisation) and even with marching through province i cannot do anything. Is there any other way of triggering a horde?

Comment: Could anyone add proper tags?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Build a huge army stack (like 30 units) and station it on that province. It will take a few years, but eventually it should trigger a horde.